# When looping through hosts in Ansible task jinja template will not use host_vars of those hosts

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In Ansible, I have playbook with task which runs against one nginx server (i.e. nginx.example.com). Purpose is to create as many reverse-proxy config files as needed (or simply: config file per host). Task includes template module. This one template ideally should be reused for many hosts.
Task:

```
- name: nginx proxied hosts
  template:
    src: proxy-template.j2
    dest: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ groups['groupname'] }}"
  when: hostvars[item].nginx_proxy is defined
```

This task will go through all hosts in group *groupname*, will use *proxy-template.j2* template and create `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/random.example.com` config file.

Becase host_vars/random.example.com has below yaml config:

```
nginx_proxy:
  target_fqdn: random.example.com
  target_resource: http://10.10.0.65
  server_ip: 10.10.0.10
```

When ansible creates config file for that host, I expect it to take values from that host yaml vars file in host_vars/random.example.com

one of the lines in proxy-template.j2:
`server_name {{ vars.nginx_proxy.target_fqdn }};`

The problem is, whilst Ansible can successfully check whether host has nginx_proxy attribute (in host_vars/random.example.com), it does not use that hosts's variables in jinja template. Ansible either fails the step for that host, or would take nginx's server variables if they are specified in host_vars (in host_vars/nginx.example.com) which should need to be.

Two outcomes:

1. host_vars/nginx.example.com and host_vars/random.example.com have nginx_proxy variables defined. both have different values.

   Outcome: On nginx server `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx.example.com` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/random.example.com` files created. But both files contain nginx server variables. random's file has nginx's file values.
2. only host_vars/random.example.com have `nginx_proxy` variables defined.

   Outcome: ansible fails with item

   > item": "random.example.com", "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'nginx_proxy'"

TLDR ansible will check whether any host has nginx_proxy in host_vars but will use only nginx's host host_vars for templating. And if host_vars/nginx.example.com does not have nginx_proxy vars, it fails.

> {"changed": false, "item": "random.example.com", "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'nginx_proxy'"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vars` (which you are not supposed to use, anyway, that's what [`vars` lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/lookup/vars.html) is for) is not the same as `hostvars[item]`. You check `hostvars` in the condition, but use `vars` in the template.

You should use `server_name {{ hostvars[item].nginx_proxy.target_fqdn }};` in your template.

---

**Explanation**

Ansible implements a host loop itself and `vars` refers to the host on which the task is being executed.

Thus you run your task twice on each host:

In the first case:

- On `random.example.com` you run for `random.example.com` and `nginx.example.com`

  Ansible uses `nginx_proxy` value from `random.example.com` (the host being executed on)
- On `nginx.example.com` you run for `random.example.com` and `nginx.example.com`

  Ansible uses `nginx_proxy` value from `nginx.example.com` (the host being executed on)

---

In the second case:

- On `random.example.com` you run for `random.example.com` (`nginx.example.com` is skipped)

  Ansible uses `nginx_proxy` value defined in `random.example.com` (the host being executed on)
- On `nginx.example.com` you run for `random.example.com` (`nginx.example.com` is skipped)

  Ansible tries to use `nginx_proxy` value defined in `nginx.example.com` (the host being executed on), but it fails.